# Paginate By Week - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-directive, angular-filters

I am trying to paginate a list of events (using ng-repeat) by week in AngularJS.  I have a custom filter working that only displays the events within the current week, but I am trying to add functionality to look at future and past weeks.

Here is the filter I am using for the event lists -

```
$scope.week = function(item) {
    var weekStart = moment().startOf('week');
    var weekEnd = moment().endOf('week');
    var eventTime = moment(item.jsdatetime);
        if (eventTime >= weekStart && eventTime <= weekEnd) return true; 
            return false;
};
```

I have tried using ng-click to call a function that uses moment.js to .add(7, 'days'); to the weekStart and weekEnd variables but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a CodePen with the basic functionality going on - http://codepen.io/drewbietron/pen/xbKNdK

Comment: could you create a basic plunker to demo what is being done? Here is a template to start you off: http://plnkr.co/edit/TkONdJqtD6nSg6s0Da59?p=info reason being is we need to see more code to help you out.

Comment: @EliteOctagon - I added a CodePen example to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `moment()` always return the current date/time.

You need to store a reference to it to a variable, and then use that for manipulations.
(*and since you have other variables depending on it, i would create a function that sets all those variables at once*)

So in the controller i changed the top part to

```
var currentDate,
    weekStart,
    weekEnd,
    shortWeekFormat = 'MMMM Do';

function setCurrentDate(aMoment){
  currentDate = aMoment,
  weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('week'),
  weekEnd = currentDate.clone().endOf('week')
}

// initialize with current date
setCurrentDate(moment());

// use these methods for displaying 
$scope.currentWeek = function(){ return currentDate.format(shortWeekFormat); }; 
$scope.currentWeekStart = function(){ return weekStart.format(shortWeekFormat); };
$scope.currentWeekEnd = function(){ return weekEnd.format(shortWeekFormat); };
```

Then create two methods for going to next/previous week

```
$scope.nextWeek = function(){
  setCurrentDate(currentDate.add(7,'days'));
};
$scope.prevWeek = function(){
  setCurrentDate(currentDate.subtract(7,'days'));
};
```

(***moment.js implements `valueOf` so you do direct comparisons***)
<strike>And finally change your week filter to actually compare the dates (*using [`.isSame()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/), [`.isBefore()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) and [`.isAfter()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)*) instead of the moment objects (*which was wrong as you cannot do direct comparisons on custom objects*)</strike>

```
$scope.week = function(item) {
    var eventTime = moment(item.jsdatetime);

    if ((eventTime.isSame(weekStart) || eventTime.isAfter(weekStart))&& 
        (eventTime.isSame(weekEnd) || eventTime.isBefore(weekEnd))) return true; 

    return false;
};
```

```
$scope.week = function(item) {
    var eventTime = moment(item.jsdatetime);

    return (eventTime >= weekStart && eventTime <= weekEnd);
};
```

(*you also, most likely, want the `ng-repeat` on the `li` elements and not the `ul`*)

**Demo at** http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/QwLRQB

Comment: I'm using the GroupBy filter https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby and calling a nested `ng-repeat` for the days so that I can get them in a calendar view and only show the days once.  So I call the initial `ng-repeat` on the `ul` and then the nested one on the `li`.

Comment: I see. you can ignore that part of the answer then :)

Comment: Ha, I should've switched it on the CodePen - had to throw together a super simplified version of the data I'm iterating through and overlooked that part of it.  I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

The weekStart and weekEnd variables don't exist outside of the scope of week(item). If you're using ngClick to call a function that tries to modify those variables, it'll just return undefined. I don't know how your layout is but I would pull those two variables outside of the week function and make them $scope variables.

Additionally, I would have ngClick call a function that would change the two $scope variables (either adds 7 or subtracts 7 depending on which direction you want to go in).

```
$scope.weekStart = moment().startOf('week');
$scope.weekEnd = moment().endOf('week');

$scope.week = function(item) {
    var eventTime = moment(item.jsdatetime);
    if (eventTime >= $scope.weekStart && eventTime <= $scope.weekEnd) return true; 
      return false;
    };

$scope.update= function(direction) {
    $scope.weekStart.add(direction, 'days');
    $scope.weekEnd.add(direction, 'days');
}
```

And create two buttons in your view:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="update(-7)">Previous week</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="update(7)">Next week</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  How would I call an ng-click function that applies to that specific filter?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood how you were using week. Now that I've looked at the code, you wouldn't use ngClick to call a function that calls the week function since week is just your filter. Instead, I would change weekStart and weekEnd to $scope variables within the week filter. In the ngClick function, you can manipulate the $scope.weekStart and $scope.weekEnd variables. I'm having issues with codepen so I can't show an example right now. However, that should be all you need to do. I've updated my answer with a small code sample.

Comment: That works great to change the week, thanks.  Any idea how I'd disable the click for going beyond a certain date - say if it's in the past?

Comment: You could try using the ngDisabled directive and have it check weekStart against the current date (or some other date that you wouldn't want to go past). edit: To clarify, I mean try using ngDisabled within the anchor tags in the view.